# SqlException was unhandled C# (cell value changed)

Tags: c#, sql, sqlexception, unhandled-exception

I want to  change a value from the cell (grid view ).When I change the value , I'm getting "SqlException was unhandled In correct syntax near '='  "error. I debugged the code I entered 50 to the cell ,I see that

> ```
>   e.value= 50 , 
>
>   dt.Rows[e.RowHandle]["Operator_ID"] = null
> ```

```
 private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        DataTable dt = gridControl1.DataSource as DataTable;
        SqlProcess process = new SqlProcess();
        process.updateQuery(@"UPDATE IE_OPERATOR_GID_KTS_PER SET CarpanDegeri ='" + e.Value +
                           "' WHERE IE_OPERATOR_GTD_KTS_PER.Operator_ID= " + dt.Rows[e.RowHandle]["Operator_ID"]);
}
```

In the table the property of Operator_ID column is NOT NULL.
How can I fix this problem?

Thanks for your answers.

PS:: I'm newer for the C# and SQL .Therefore can you answer explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly because you're constructing your SQL with the values added manually rather than using parameters. Change the SQL to:

```
UPDATE IE_OPERATOR_GID_KTS_PER SET CarpanDegeri = @CarpanDegeri
WHERE IE_OPERATOR_GTD_KTS_PER.Operator_ID = @OperatorID
```

... and then supply values for those parameters. It's not clear to me what `SqlProcess` is, but if it doesn't support parameterized queries then it's fundamentally broken :(

See the [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) documentation for an example of how to use parameters. You should *always* do this for values:

- It avoids [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- It avoids data conversion issues
- It keeps your code (SQL) and data (parameter values) separate - look how much easier it is to read the SQL above than the version with all the string concatenation